# Weird emacs graphics on popup windows

Tags: buffers, frames

I have emacs 25.1.1 installed on my kubuntu 16.10 with gtk-3.18.9.

Those popup messages that you get with emacs when you exit without saving:

Those are looking very strange and taking up my full screen. (I don't know what they are called and it is making it very hard to isolate the issue)

I am attaching the screenshot:

[image]

As you can see the popup takes up my entire screen and looks weird.

Has anyone experienced similar issues, or can at least point me in the right direction so i can find out what is causing the issue.
Thanks.

**EDIT**

This Seems to be solved when I force geometry restrictions on the windows manager settings.
But that kind of breaks the UI with some interleaving black blocks when I try to maximize.
To solve that I resized manually, instead of maximizing, and forced the window manager to remember size and position.
Pretty lame workaround, but I am happy with it for now.

Comment: Do you see this also if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, recursively bisect your init file to find the culprit. If yes, provide a step-by-step recipe to repro the problem, and consider reporting it as a bug: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Were you previously telling your window manager to maximise windows? I've certainly seen this kind of thing with tiling window managers (which like to automatically set window sizes, and consequently small dialogue boxes can be full-screen, or otherwise over-sized), but it's never been an Emacs issue in my experience.

Comment: @phils Yes, now the popup issue is solved, but there are still redrawing issues, seems to be a long running bug with gtk, which resurfaces again and again.

Comment: I can't help, other than to recommend compiling emacs `--with-x-toolkit=lucid` which ought to avoid GTK issues entirely (especially the well-known "Emacs might crash when run in daemon mode and the X11 connection is unexpectedly lost." problem with http://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85715 ).